# How to proxy proxy domain name to internal app server URL in Nginx?

Tags: django, nginx, reverse-proxy, appserver

I have an internal app server (Django+gunicorn) running behind an Nginx reverse proxy on a private port (listening on port 5000, for example.)

There are several Django apps installed in the app server, mapped to separate base paths.  Example:

```
/app1
/app2
```

Where `/app1` serves up content for `domain1.com` and `/app2` serves content for `domain2.com`.

I'd like to silently reverse proxy incoming requests for specific hostnames to the related backend app, while preserving the path forwarded to the internal app server:

```
http://domain1.com/foo --> /app1/foo
http://domain1.com/bar/bletch --> /app1/bar/bletch

http://domain2.com/alpha/bravo --> /app2/alpha/bravo
```

I suppose you could say I'm trying to set up a simple 'virtual hosting' configuration but I want to use a shared back-end app server instance.

Key point: I don't want the visitor's browser to see the redirected URL structure.  So when the client browser hits http://domain1.com/foo, the correct content is served up but the browser doesn't see a redirect.

I've done some basic work with Nginx (still learning) and I'm looking for example Nginx configurations demonstrating secure and efficient ways to accomplish this goal.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15579696/1309774) here's a configuration that seems to work as desired.

For `app1` running on `http://localhost:8000/app1_path` :

```
upstream app1 {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /app1_path$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://app1;
    }
}
```

So, one could repeat this pattern as many times as desired for each hostname->app/path pair.