# rewrite subdomain url in nginx to backend-server

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I'm running nginx in front of my django (gunicorn) app. I want calls made to:

**api.mydomain.com**

to be redirected to:

**localhost:8080/api**

I now have this, but this obviously doesn't work:

```
server {
    listen     80;
    server_name  api.mydomain.com;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    location / {
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080/api;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can combine proxy pass with rewrite

```
server {
    listen     80;
    server_name  api.mydomain.com;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    location / {
       index  index.html index.htm;
       rewrite ^(.*)$ /api$1 break;
       proxy_pass   http://localhost:8080;
    }

}
```

Comment: What should I do if I also want to serve my frontend app on 'mydomain.com'?

Comment: Just create a separate server block with the server_name mydomain.com and set the root directive to the directory containing the front end files you want to serve.

Answer (score 1):

add a new location block like this

```
location ~ api.mydomain.com
{
    fastcgi_pass localhost:8080;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/Django script's folder's name/$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```